# How to import typing data and function from another file typescript?

Tags: typescript, p5.js

I have 2 files `sketch.ts` and `lib.ts`.

- `sketch.ts` includes main code.
- `lib.ts` includes interfaces and utility functions

Now I am using the library `p5.js`, which is unique in that it is a canvas library where you define functions like mouseClicked, or preLoad and the library uses the functions and runs them when that event fires. The problem with this is if the functions are not defined by the time that those events fire they don't run. This setup was working fine with one file but it was becoming rather cluttered in one file so I decided to move some things to a second file.

The second file `lib.ts` is structured as a namespacee that contains other namespaces that contain interfaces or functions. e.g

```
namespace lib{
    export namespace types{
    export interface example{
    //data
    }
    //more interfaces
    }
    export namespace functions{
    //functions
    }

}
export default lib;
```

Now for the problem, which is `How do you import both typing data and functions from another file?`
Currently I have working

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
    <script type="module" async src="./dist/lib.js"></script>
    <script src="./dist/sketch.js"></script>
```

In lib.ts I have

```
declare global{
   export namespace types{
   export interface example{
   //data
   }
}
}
namespace functions{
   //functions
   }

declare global {
   interface Window { functions: typeof functions; }
}
window.functions = functions;
```

along with an `/// <reference path="./lib.ts"/>` in sketch.ts.

I have 2 *exports* one with typing data and one with functions.
Is there a better way to achieve this?

I have tried importing lib.ts from sketch.ts with an import statement but that requires setting `type="module"` on the `<script src="sketch.ts">` which messes up the execution order which messes up the p5 library.

I also have read and tried to understand https://gist.github.com/jakub-g/385ee6b41085303a53ad92c7c8afd7a6, but was unable to implement a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you would be better off using a bundler (such as [Webpack](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/integrating-with-build-tools.html#webpack), or [Browserify](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/integrating-with-build-tools.html#browserify)) to compile your Typescript modules and their dependencies. This would allow you to use Node.js modules and ES6 import statements instead of Typescript Namespaces and `/// <reference />` tags. For more information about this difference see [this article from the Typescript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html).

It looks like you're currently using a mix of Typescript Namespaces and Modules, and presumably compiling your `.ts` files into individual `.js` modules. This works in theory, assuming the target web browser supports ES6 modules, however there is no way to import `p5.js` as an ES6 module. The reason bundlers like `Webpack` and `Browserify` can make `import p5 from 'p5';` work is because they also support other module formats that predate ES6.

If you absolutely do not want to use a bundler, and instead just compile with the Typescript compiler, then you can use Typescript Namespaces and  `/// <reference />` tags exclusively (no modules). And then compile your Typescript to a single file with a command like `tsc --outFile compiled.js main.ts`. This will allow you to include your generated javascript like a normal script (not a module). The last thing that you seem to be missing is a [type declaration file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html) for p5.js. There does exist an npm package, [`@types/p5`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/p5) that contains declarations for p5.js, however it seems to only work with ES6 style imports, not `/// <reference />` tags. The good news is that I was able to make some modifications to get this working. Here's a [simple example in a GitHub](https://github.com/sflanker/Typescript-P5js-Static), and a [live instance on Replit.com](https://replit.com/@KumuPaul/Typescript-P5js-Static?v=1)

Comment: @MrNNP Let me know if this does or doesn't answer your question. It was a little hard to tell exactly what you are trying to do from your original question. If I missed something I'd be happy to clarify.